# Display ListPopupWindow on most left of the screen

Tags: android

I could display ListPopupWindow on most left of the screen by following code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateActionView() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    final View actionItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_table_view_action_provider, null);

    final ImageButton button = (ImageButton) actionItem.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(mContext);
            mListPopupWindow.setAnchorView(actionItem);
            mListPopupWindow.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mListPopupWindow.setModal(true);
            mListPopupWindow.setContentWidth(150);

            // Display mListPopupWindow on most left of the screen
            mListPopupWindow.setHorizontalOffset(-1000);


            mListPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(ListTableViewActionProvider.this);

            mListPopupWindow.show();
            mListPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(ListTableViewActionProvider.this);
        }
    });

    return actionItem;
}
```

"mListPopupWindow.setHorizontalOffset(-1000);" is too bad.
Is there other solutions?

Comment: try having the outermost layout/ViewGroup of  the activity as the anchor and with an offset of 0.
or you can also use a PopupWindow and give x and y as 0

Comment: You can anchor to the home icon, use `findViewById(android.R.id.home)` to get the view. The popup will not be flush with the left edge of the screen though; the home icon has some margin on the left (to make room for the "up" affordance arrow).

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831889/4797289