# How to show popupWindow at underneath TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I want to be able to show my PopupWindow underneath my TextView. I have followed tutorials and still unable to get it to display where I want it to.

[image]

I want it to show underneath the Key (TextView).

My Xml Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/layout_master"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.test.myview.MainActivity">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView0"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="Options" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/tagSpinner" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="sampleTxt" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/tagKey"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Type me.."></EditText>
                </LinearLayout>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="value" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/tagval"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Enter value"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:text="Button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="btnclick"
                    android:id="@+id/aaaa" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Edit: I also don't mind if it gets cut off Screen

Comment: How are you actually showing your `PopupWindow`? Share the code.

Comment: @azizbekian@bhandari, Edit: I have found the issue, it was due to the Width of the popupWindow. The width was pushing the Tip to the left so moving it away from the TextView. If i set the Width to something smaller then it will solve the problem.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52831889/4797289

Answer (score 1):

```
Clicking the button in the main screen try the below code:-

 Button buttonAction;
        final PopupWindow mPopupwindow;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(mActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,layouttext,false);
        mPopupwindow = new PopupWindow(mView, 300, 300, true);
        mPopupwindow.showAsDropDown(layouttext,0,5);
        buttonAction = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAction);
        buttonAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPopupwindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
```